# Speed up Least_square scipy

Tags: python, scipy, least-squares

How can I speed up the function `least_square`? We have six variables (3 orientation angles and 3 axis translation) that need to be optimized. We apply two sets of 3D points, two sets of points on the plane and a projection matrix to the input of the function.

```
dSeed = np.zeros(6)
optRes = least_squares(minReproj, dSeed, method='lm', max_nfev=600,
    args=(points_prev, points_cur, d3d_prev, d3d_cur, Proj1))
```

This function minimizes the error of forward-backward projection of points.

```
def minReproj(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix):
    Rmat = genEulerZXZ(dof[0], dof[1], dof[2]) # my function
    translationArray = np.array([[dof[3]], [dof[4]], [dof[5]]])
    temp = np.hstack((Rmat, translationArray))
    perspectiveProj = np.vstack((temp, [0, 0, 0, 1]))

    numPoints = d2dPoints1.shape[0]
    errorA = np.zeros((numPoints,3))
    errorB = np.zeros((numPoints,3))

    forwardProj = np.matmul(w2cMatrix, perspectiveProj)
    backwardProj = np.matmul(w2cMatrix, np.linalg.inv(perspectiveProj))

    for i in range(numPoints):
        Ja = np.ones((3))
        Jb = np.ones((3))
        Wa = np.ones((4))
        Wb = np.ones((4))

        Ja[0:2] = d2dPoints1[i,:]
        Jb[0:2] = d2dPoints2[i,:]
        Wa[0:3] = d3dPoints1[i,:]
        Wb[0:3] = d3dPoints2[i,:]

        JaPred = np.matmul(forwardProj, Wb)
        JaPred /= JaPred[-1]
        e1 = Ja - JaPred

        JbPred = np.matmul(backwardProj, Wa)
        JbPred /= JbPred[-1]
        e2 = Jb - JbPred

        errorA[i,:] = e1
        errorB[i,:] = e2

    residual = np.vstack((errorA,errorB))
    return residual.flatten()
```

```
def genEulerZXZ(psi, theta, sigma):
    c1 = cos(psi)
    s1 = sin(psi)
    c2 = cos(theta)
    s2 = sin(theta)
    c3 = cos(sigma)
    s3 = sin(sigma)

    mat = np.zeros((3,3))

    mat[0,0] = (c1 * c3) - (s1 * c2 * s3)
    mat[0,1] = (-c1 * s3) - (s1 * c2 * c3)
    mat[0,2] = (s1 * s2)

    mat[1,0] = (s1 * c3) + (c1 * c2 * s3)
    mat[1,1] = (-s1 * s3) + (c1 * c2 * c3)
    mat[1,2] = (-c1 * s2)

    mat[2,0] = (s2 * s3)
    mat[2,1] = (s2 * c3)
    mat[2,2] = c2

    return mat
```

This optimization takes 0.2 to 0.4 seconds, and this is too much. Maybe you know how to speed up this process?
Or maybe there is another way to find the relative rotation and translation of two point sets?
For rpoleski:

```
       96    0.023    0.000   19.406    0.202 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py:240(least_squares)
     4548    0.132    0.000   18.986    0.004 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py:801(fun_wrapped)
       96    0.012    0.000   18.797    0.196 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/_lsq/least_squares.py:42(call_minpack)
     4548   11.102    0.002   18.789    0.004 /home/pi/helperFunctions.py:29(minimizeReprojection)
```

Comment: Your `minReproj()` lacks `return` statement. Are you sure you've posted right code?

Comment: Added part of the code

Comment: The function `genEulerZXZ()` was not disclosed. Aside of that, I'd profile your `minReproj()` func and see where the bottlenecks are, since most of `least_square()` time is likely to be spent within your function. I am fairly confident you could avoid / reduce a couple of relatively expensive `*stack()`, some of the memory allocations and perhaps some `matmul()` and some `linalg.inv()`, If anything the function may be JIT-compiled with Numba, which may buy you some speed when looping through the points.

Comment: I added genEulerZXZ. I removed it so as not to enlarge the question

Comment: Have you tried profiling it? One possibility is `python -m cProfile script.py`. If your angles are between 0 and pi/2 then you can easily speed up sin/cos calculations using Pythagorean trigonometric identity.

Comment: I tried. I add largest time output.

Comment: You have to analyze it, i.e., find the part that contributes most.

Comment: I added output in question. As I understand it, minReprojection takes the longest time

Comment: Are `cos` and `sin` from `math` or from `numpy` or from something else?

Comment: From `math` library

Comment: Would you be able to provide some ideas of the shape of the input arguments of `minReproj()`?

Comment: Two sets of 3d points from a stereo reconstruction at time A and B. Also two sets of 2d points from left image of stereocamera at time A and B. And reprojection matrix of left camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, during the [`scipy.optimize.least_squares()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html), the largest portion of the time is spent in computing the residuals, which in your case take the form of the code in `minReproj()`.

However, the code you provided in `minReproj()` seems to have a sub-optimal memory management, which could be greatly improved with pre-allocation. This would result in significant speed gains.

---

For example, `vstack()` and `hstack()` suffer a significant penalty from having to copy their arguments into the memory of their final result. Consider, the first few lines of `minReproj()`, which I regrouped in `gen_affine_OP()`. These can be rewritten as `gen_affine()` with much better timings (I have also rewritten `gen_euler_zxz()` to not allocate new memory):

```
import numpy as np
from math import sin, cos


def gen_euler_zxz(result, psi, theta, sigma):
    c1 = cos(psi)
    s1 = sin(psi)
    c2 = cos(theta)
    s2 = sin(theta)
    c3 = cos(sigma)
    s3 = sin(sigma)
    result[0,0] = (c1 * c3) - (s1 * c2 * s3)
    result[0,1] = (-c1 * s3) - (s1 * c2 * c3)
    result[0,2] = (s1 * s2)
    result[1,0] = (s1 * c3) + (c1 * c2 * s3)
    result[1,1] = (-s1 * s3) + (c1 * c2 * c3)
    result[1,2] = (-c1 * s2)
    result[2,0] = (s2 * s3)
    result[2,1] = (s2 * c3)
    result[2,2] = c2
    return result


def gen_affine(dof):
    result = np.zeros((4, 4))
    gen_euler_zxz(result[:3, :3], dof[0], dof[1], dof[2])
    result[:3, 3] = dof[3:]
    result[3, 3] = 1
    return result


def gen_affine_OP(dof):
    Rmat = gen_euler_zxz(np.empty((3, 3)), dof[0], dof[1], dof[2])
    translationArray = np.array([[dof[3]], [dof[4]], [dof[5]]])
    temp = np.hstack((Rmat, translationArray))
    return np.vstack((temp, [0, 0, 0, 1]))


dof = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
%timeit gen_affine_OP(dof)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 16.6 µs per loop
%timeit gen_affine(dof)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.02 µs per loop
```

---

Similarly, the `residual = np.vstack((errorA,errorB))` call can be avoided, by defining a larger residual and providing a view on it for `errorA` and `errorB`.

Another example is when creating `Ja`, `Jb`, `Wa`, `Wb`:

```
def func_OP(numPoints):
    for i in range(numPoints):
        Ja = np.ones((3))
        Jb = np.ones((3))
        Wa = np.ones((4))
        Wb = np.ones((4))


def func(n):
    Ja = np.empty(3)
    Jb = np.empty(3)
    Wa = np.empty(3)
    Wb = np.empty(3)
    for i in range(n):
        Ja[:] = 1
        Jb[:] = 1
        Wa[:] = 1
        Wb[:] = 1


%timeit func_OP(1000)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 9.31 ms per loop
%timeit func(1000)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.2 ms per loop
```

---

Also, `.flatten()` is making a copy you do not need, while `.ravel()` will just return a view, but that is enough for your needs and comes up much faster:

```
a = np.ones((300, 300))
%timeit a.ravel()
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 215 ns per loop
%timeit a.flatten()
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 113 µs per loop
```

---

The final remarks concerns the speeding up of your main loop.
I do not devise a simple vectorized rewriting for that, but you can speed things up with Numba (as long as it compiles in non-object mode).

To do so, you need to also JIT-decorate `gen_euler_zxz()` and you need to replace `np.matmul()` calls with `np.dot()` (because `np.matmul()` is not supported by Numba.

---

Eventually, the revised `minReproj()` would look like:

```
from math import sin, cos
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


matmul = np.dot


@nb.jit
def gen_euler_zxz(result, psi, theta, sigma):
    c1 = cos(psi)
    s1 = sin(psi)
    c2 = cos(theta)
    s2 = sin(theta)
    c3 = cos(sigma)
    s3 = sin(sigma)
    result[0, 0] = (c1 * c3) - (s1 * c2 * s3)
    result[0, 1] = (-c1 * s3) - (s1 * c2 * c3)
    result[0, 2] = (s1 * s2)
    result[1, 0] = (s1 * c3) + (c1 * c2 * s3)
    result[1, 1] = (-s1 * s3) + (c1 * c2 * c3)
    result[1, 2] = (-c1 * s2)
    result[2, 0] = (s2 * s3)
    result[2, 1] = (s2 * c3)
    result[2, 2] = c2
    return result


@nb.jit
def minReproj(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix):
    perspectiveProj = np.zeros((4, 4))
    gen_euler_zxz(perspectiveProj[:3, :3], dof[0], dof[1], dof[2])
    perspectiveProj[:3, 3] = dof[3:]
    perspectiveProj[3, 3] = 1

    numPoints = d2dPoints1.shape[0]
    residual = np.empty((2 * numPoints, 3))

    forwardProj = matmul(w2cMatrix, perspectiveProj)
    backwardProj = matmul(w2cMatrix, np.linalg.inv(perspectiveProj))

    Ja = np.empty(3)
    Jb = np.empty(3)
    Wa = np.empty(4)
    Wb = np.empty(4)
    for i in range(numPoints):
        j = i + numPoints

        Ja[2] = Jb[2] = 1.0
        Wa[3] = Wb[3] = 1.0
        Ja[0:2] = d2dPoints1[i, :]
        Jb[0:2] = d2dPoints2[i, :]
        Wa[0:3] = d3dPoints1[i, :]
        Wb[0:3] = d3dPoints2[i, :]

        JaPred = matmul(forwardProj, Wb)
        JaPred /= JaPred[-1]
        residual[i, :] = Ja - JaPred

        JbPred = matmul(backwardProj, Wa)
        JbPred /= JbPred[-1]
        residual[j, :] = Jb - JbPred
    return residual.ravel()
```

Testing it on some toy data shows significant speed-ups, which become drammatic when using Numba appropriately:

```
n = 10000
dof = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
d2dPoints1 = np.random.random((n, 2))
d2dPoints2 = np.random.random((n, 2))
d3dPoints1 = np.random.random((n, 3))
d3dPoints2 = np.random.random((n, 3))
w2cMatrix = np.random.random((3, 4))
x = minReproj_OP(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
y = minReproj(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
z = minReproj_nb(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
print(np.allclose(x, y))
# True
print(np.allclose(x, z))
# True


%timeit minReproj_OP(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 277 ms per loop
%timeit minReproj(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 177 ms per loop
%timeit minReproj_nb(dof, d2dPoints1, d2dPoints2, d3dPoints1, d3dPoints2, w2cMatrix)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.69 ms per loop
```

Comment: @user11278733 please report back if it works correctly and what speed gain do you observe

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use RPI and get error: `Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Func tion "minReproj" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'gen_euler_zxz': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>                                                                                                                                                            `

Comment: @user11278733 Decorate `gen_euler_zxz()` too with `@nb.jit` or remove `@nb.jit` from `minReproj()`. You should observe some speed-up regardless of Numba.

Comment: If I calculate the optimal orientation angles in the gen_euler_zxz () function, how do I call it correctly?
`R = gen_euler_zxz(optRes.x[0], optRes.x[1], optRes.x[2])`

Comment: @user11278733 You need to provide a suitable NumPy array as first argument. `gen_euler_zxz()` does not allocate memory. So, something like `R = gen_euler_zxz(np.empty((3, 3)), optRes.x[0], optRes.x[1], optRes.x[2])` or `R = np.empty((3, 3)); gen_euler_zxz(R, optRes.x[0], optRes.x[1], optRes.x[2])` is enough.

Comment: @user11278733 but if you want to generate the full affinr matrix, why don't you use `gen_affine(optRes.x)` directly?

Comment: Test old and new variant of code. Old code takes ~22.8, new 21.2 seconds. Although the camera is in one place, discrepancies can occur.

Comment: @user11278733 I thought this optimization was taking 0.2 to 0.4 seconds. Where is this 21.2 seconds coming from? Are you sure this code is the bottleneck? Are you using the same data? If not, the discrepancies may come from the data itself.

Comment: I use a video stream, and the discrepancies can be small, even though the camera is stationary. If you run cProfile, the optimization process takes ~73% of the time.

Comment: @user11278733 check out the updated code. I tested that it gives 100% identical results and also managed to let Numba do the correct optimizations.

Comment: If I use Numba, I get an error. Yes, the results will be the same. But I work with a real video stream, so there may be slight deviations

Comment: @user11278733 I am on version `'0.48.0'`. If you have that, it should work correctly.

Comment: I can not install `0.48.0` version on RPI but can install `0.49.0` or `0.49.1`. I use `0.49.1` version. But I get an error `Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "minReproj" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of Function(<built-in function zeros>) with argument(s) of type(s): (UniTuple(Literal[int](4) x 2), dtype=Function(<class 'float'>))`

Comment: @user11278733 Did you copy-paste the code from above? It looks like you still have the `dtype` parameter set in `np.zeros()`, which you should remove.

Comment: You fixed the code, I did not notice. I will test it tomorrow and write about the results

Comment: The code runs without errors, but now the bulk of the code works differently. I convert input image to grayscale, but I see color image. And code not work correctly.This is probably due to the fact that the numba changes the source code.

Comment: Unless you are running in overflow issues, Numba JIT accelerated code should work precisely as the non-accelerated one. I briefly tested it on random data, and observed no difference. If you have evidence of otherwise behaviour, please file a bug to Numba developers. However, I find it way more likely that you are overlooking some bug you introduced in the code you are not showing, the code in the post, as far as my tests tell, is OK.

Comment: Maybe you can send it personally?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I don’t know why it worked strange in the morning, although I was definitely updating the file. Can you tell me how to do jit-compilation at the beginning of the file assembly? Because it turns out that the file runs for 1 second, then jit-compiles for 10 seconds, and then works again. Until a function is called, it does not jit-compile.

Comment: Precisely. To trigger compilation just call the function with dummy inputs once.

Comment: Could you tell me how best to look for correspondences between stereo images? We have rectified images, therefore, similar points should be on + - one horizontal line.

Comment: I think you may want to ask a new question (and perhaps vote/accept existing answer(s) of the current question). If you think it is appropriate you could reference this one.